# Problem importing documentai module from Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to run the quickstart code snippet from Google Cloud tutorials and somehow the line

```
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai
```

I get this error:

> Cannot find reference 'documentai_v1' in 'imported module google.cloud'

The only module which is accessible for import is Storage. Same issue with Pub/Sub, BigQuery, etc.

The Google imports in `requirements.txt` are:

```
google-api-core==2.10.2
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-auth==2.12.0
google-cloud-documentai==2.0.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.4
```

```
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai

from tabulate import tabulate

def quickstart(project_id: str, location: str, processor_id: str, file_path: str, mime_type: str):

    # You must set the api_endpoint if you use a location other than 'us', e.g.:
    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")

    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project_id/locations/location/processor/processor_id
    name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)

    # Read the file into memory
    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()

    # Load Binary Data into Document AI RawDocument Object
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content=image_content, mime_type=mime_type)

    # Configure the process request
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(name=name, raw_document=raw_document)

    result = client.process_document(request=request)

    # For a full list of Document object attributes, please reference this page:
    # https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/documentai/latest/google.cloud.documentai_v1.types.Document
    document = result.document

    # Read the text recognition output from the processor
    print("The document contains the following text:")
    print(document.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code samples have been updated recently, you can get [the most up to date version here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python).

You shouldn't need to use:

```py
from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai
```

You can just import

```py
from google.cloud import documentai
```

(It will default to the v1 endpoint)

It doesn't seem like the requirements were installed correctly.

Try running

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-documentai
```

Or

```
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

(Be sure to update your `requirements.txt` to use the latest Python Client Library version [2.15.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-documentai)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are importing the module in the wrong way. Instead of importing `from google.cloud import documentai_v1 as documentai` try importing this module: `from google.cloud import documentai` or if you are importing **documentai_v1** refer this import statement:

```
from google.cloud import documentai_v1
```

In code where ever you want to use call the documentai_v1 functions like below:

```
documentai_v1.Document.to_json(my_document_object)
```